# I Want to Join a Table That I'm Counting From in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm attempting to view a table and want to view results "A" only if they have a certain freqeuency, it will be variable, but the first one will be 2. This is what I have thus far (it's a financial db):

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A)
FROM Transactions
INNER JOIN Transactions on 
????
GROUP BY A
```

What do I join it on, do I need to give my "count" result a name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'certain frequency'? How should we know the relation of a table to itself if all we know is that it contains some field named 'A' without any details whatsoever? Also, if you self-join a table, you'll need to add aliases to the table.

Comment: Hi, I just basically am looking to write a query that will return only those that have a count of 2 from the table "Transactions". Is there an easier way to do this than joining a table to a count? Can I have a (WHERE) clause that says WHERE COUNT = 2? How would I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A)
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(A) >= 2;
```

If you want to show the original rows, you can `join` back to the data using a subquery:

```
select t.*
from transactions as t inner join
     (select a
      from transactions
      group by a
      having count(a) >= 2
     ) as ta
     on t.a = ta.a;
```

Comment: Hi, this is close, is there any way that I can display the whole transactions table? All columns that just meeting the having = 2 criteria?

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I can just add in the having count function in the middle of any query? I didn't know that.

Comment: @fordo19 . . . After a `group by`, you can add it.